# Гепард — самое быстрое наземное животное на З/земле

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Гепард — самое быстрое наземное животное на з/Земле.

С какой буквы написать *земля*?

---

В одном из источников увидел написание с маленькой буквы. Писали, что название планеты пишется с большой, только когда речь об астрономии. Но я не могу быть полностью уверен, что здесь с маленькой.

Comment: с маленькой, конечно, астрономический Гепард - это разве что какая звезда

Answer (score 1):

[**ЗЕМЛЯ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F)
**1.** [с прописной буквы] Третья планета Солнечной системы, вращающаяся вокруг своей оси и вокруг Солнца, орбита которой находится между Венерой и Марсом.
**3.** Суша, земная твердь (в отличие от водного или воздушного пространства).

**Животное** — всякое живое существо, исключая растение.

• Если мы говорим о животных, которые бегают-прыгают, то правильно, думаю, так:
Самое быстрое животное на земле (земля — поверхность).
Самое быстрое сухопутное животное.

• Если мы говорим о животных, которые плавают:
Самое быстрое животное в воде.
Самое быстрое морское (водное) животное.

• Если мы говорим о животных, которые летают:
Самое быстрое животное в воздухе.
Самое быстрое летающее животное.

•• *Гепард — самое быстрое наземное животное на з/Земле.*

Про гепарда я бы написала так:
Гепард — самое быстрое наземное животное.
Или так:
Гепард — самое быстрое сухопутное животное на Земле (на планете Земля; избегаем повторов: *наземный — Земля*).

*Синий кит — самое большое животное на Земле* (В. П. Максаковский. Географическая картина мира).
*— Кажется, единственное сухопутное животное на Земле, вооруженное электричеством* (Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Страна багровых туч).

[Самые быстрые](https://www.gismeteo.ru/news/animals/top-10-samyh-bystryh-zhivotnyh-na-planete-i-gepard-daleko-ne-na-pervom-meste/)

Answer (score 0):

"самое быстрое животное на Земле" - среди всех животных на планете.

"самое быстрое животное на земле" - среди всех животных, живущих на суше (а не в воде или воздухе).